# Magento diplaying category tree dynamically

Tags: php, magento

I need to display my category tree as a list in a responsive menu.
The idea is to display the highest level categories. and create dynamically a list that will be displayed for each category that has children.

I stumbled upon a code that helped me a bit, but i can't figure how to get the job done.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$rootCatId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild){
    $allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId));

    $class = ($isChild) ? "sub-cat-list" : "cat-list";
    $html .= '<ul class="'.$class.'">';
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(7);
    foreach ($children as $category) {
    {
        $html .= '<li>'.$category->getName()."";
        $subcats = $category->getChildren();
        if($subcats != ''){
            $html .= getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
$catlistHtml = getTreeCategories($rootCatId, false);

echo $catlistHtml;

?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to create category tree:

```
<?php
    $rootCatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootCatId);
    $output= '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
        $count = $cat->getProductCount();
        $output .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()) . '">' . $category->getName() . "</a>";
        if ($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
            $array .=  get_categories($children);
        }
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
    echo $output . '</ul>';
 ?>
```

For the effects of showing / hiding categories and subcategories, you can use plain css or jQuery / Prototype.

Comment: Thank you for the help , this code works fine, but where i have problems is when the category tree is deeper : a category that have many child categories , who themselves have many child categories ..etc